# Deniable encryption for Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-encryption

Browsing on wikipedia about some cryptography topics, I found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption, and it sounds like a good idea, so I want to try it.

I noticed that some programs I always use were already using it behind the scenes. See 
[OTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging)

Anyway, my questions are:

1) Is there any recommended software for this?

2) Is it possible to have full disk deniable encryption? Currently I'm using the regular full disk encryption that ships with Ubuntu 12.04.

**UPDATE**

From the link posted by @Bob, about Truecrypt:

"There has been no known comprehensive review of the source code by a qualified cryptographer. Thorough security code review and testing is hard, tedious, and painstaking work, and very few people have the skills to do it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TrueCrypt does support a form of deniable encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt#Plausible_deniability). Essentially, you have an encrypted container within an encrypted container. The first encrypted container might be proven to exist, but the second cannot (without the correct key). So you could give someone the key to the first layer, but they never know there's a second layer.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper As long as it's not the OS disk, you should be able to encrypt the entire disk.

Comment: I updated my post, found something ugly about Truecrypt =(

Comment: @HappyDeveloper On the plus side, [government agencies haven't been able to crack it yet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt#Operation_Satyagraha) :\

Comment: @HappyDeveloper The [source code](http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads2) is available for review, and [others have raised doubts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:TrueCrypt#Developers.2FOwners_identities_and_related_concerns) about that particular section of that article on Wikipedia. There is also currently no source for that quote you added to your question.

Answer (score -1):

[DM-Steg](http://dmsteg.sourceforge.net/) is a rather new on this deniable encryption and more targeted for Linux and its device mapper. This has great potential and if you're a bit a of a Linux hacker you should try it out.

Comment: Could you please describe the mecahnisms a little?